# Escaping a lengthy Bash command to use with PHP exec()

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell

I have a semi-lengthy shell command that I need to execute from within php.  I feel like I have everything properly escaped, however it is not working properly when executed from php's exec() function.  When I run the command with exec() it exits without error, but does not run properly.

I am comparing a list file that has email addresses with additional pipe delimited information against a text file containing the md5 version of email addresses to suppress from the original list.

Here is the bash command:

```
while read line ; do email=`echo "$line" | cut -d '|' -f1` ; if [ $(E=`echo -en "$email" | md5sum | awk '{print $1}'`; grep $E /path/to/suppressions | head -1 ;) ] ; then continue ; else echo $line ; fi done < /path/to/emails
```

/path/to/suppressions is a text file, containing the md5 version of an email address to suppress (it contains the md5 for "emailtosuppress@domain.com":

```
edb5feb3be7d0a4e1e250ccdf0c04ace
```

/path/to/emails is a text file containing a list of email addresses with some other delimeted information:

```
emailtokeep@domain.com|1000|1
emailtosuppress@domain.com|1000|1
```

When the command is executed in bash, the output is simply the email address that does NOT exist in the suppression list, and it works flawless:

```
emailtokeep@domain.com|1000|1
```

The trouble I am having is when I execute this same command with exec() in php, it outputs all the lines from the "emails" file, without suppressing any matches from the suppression file.

```
$supCommand = 'while read line ; do email=`echo "$line" | cut -d \'|\' -f1` ; if [ $(E=`echo -en "$email" | md5sum | awk \'{print $1}\'`; grep $E /path/to/suppressions | head -1 ;) ] ; then continue ; else echo $line ; fi done < /path/to/emails' ;
exec($supCommand, $supStatus) ;
print_r($supStatus) ;
```

I enclosed the command in single quotes, and escaped the four instances of single quotes within the command.  If anyone has any ideas I would be extremely GRATEFUL.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: can't you do all these in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
<?php
    $bash = '
        mapfile -t md5sums < suppressions
        function md5 { printf "%s" "$1" | md5sum | cut -f1 -d" "; }
        while IFS="|" read -r email b c; do 
            this_md5=$(md5 "$email")
            for suppress in "${md5sums[@]}"; do
                [[ $this_md5 == $suppress ]] && continue 2
            done
            echo "$email|$b|$c" 
        done < emails
    ';
    $cmd = "bash -c '$bash'";
    $keep = passthru($cmd);
    print($keep);
?>
```